# Galculator weird behavior

Tags: math

Why does `galculator` miscalculate `4000225165312/512` and gets `781293977.6`?

**Note** This is intended as a **canonical question** cautioning against the unreflected use of `galculator` 1.2.4.

- Please do not use it. Here [(1)](https://github.com/galculator/galculator/issues/56) [(2)](https://github.com/galculator/galculator/issues/49) [(3)](https://github.com/galculator/galculator/issues/40) are some good reasons why.
- I've already uninstalled it because I was ashamed by "my" calculations today. I've replaced it with `mate-calc` which computes all of these expressions properly.

Comment: To be honest (3) *could* contain an explanation but I'm too stupid today to understand it.

Comment: I take this question as a warning. Probably the high degree of accuracy of the `galculator` is not its strong point.

Comment: If you want a decent GUI calculator, two good choices are [mate-calc](https://wiki.mate-desktop.org/mate-desktop/applications/mate-calc/) and [speedcrunch](http://www.speedcrunch.org/).  Both are accurate and both have a great history feature allowing you to see and/or re-use & edit previous calculations (IMO history alone is worth it...I've been using speedcrunch for years because of this).

Comment: Also, weird rounding errors are an essential part of the galculator project's Glorious Vision. Anybody who isn't capable of understanding that doesn't deserve to be included in the target audience.

Answer (score 3):

Galculator only handles [a pre-determined number of digits in decimal mode](https://github.com/galculator/galculator/blob/master/src/general_functions.c#L454), [specifically 12](https://github.com/galculator/galculator/blob/master/src/display.h#L24). Input beyond that is ignored!

So trying to calculate 4000225165312 ÷ 512 ends up calculating 400022516531 ÷ 512, *i.e.* not quite 781293977.6.